# Nunit SetUp and TearDown not run when using TestDecorator Addin

Tags: nunit

I'm trying to write a TestDecorator Addin for Nunit (2.6.4).
But enabling the addin prevents setup and teardown running for any decorated test, even when the decorator itself does nothing (deferring all calls to the real test as shown below).

Any ideas why this would prevent SetUp/TearDown from running?

**Decorator:**

```
public class DoNothingTestDecorator : Test
{
    private readonly Test concrete;

    public DoNothingTestDecorator(Test concrete) : base(concrete.TestName)
    {
        this.concrete = concrete;
    }

    public override TestResult Run(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter)
    {
        return concrete.Run(listener, filter);
    }

    public override string TestType
    {
        get { return concrete.TestType; }
    }

    public override object Fixture
    {
        get { return concrete.Fixture; }
        set { concrete.Fixture = value; }
    }

    public override int CountTestCases(ITestFilter filter)
    {
        return concrete.CountTestCases(filter);
    }

    public override Type FixtureType
    {
        get { return concrete.FixtureType; }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return concrete.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return concrete.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool IsSuite
    {
        get { return concrete.IsSuite; }
    }

    public override string MethodName
    {
        get { return concrete.MethodName; }
    }

    public override int TestCount
    {
        get { return concrete.TestCount; }
    }

    public override IList Tests
    {
        get { return concrete.Tests; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return concrete.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Addin:**

```
[NUnitAddin(
    Type=ExtensionType.Core,
    Name = "TestDecoratorAddin",
    Description="Attempts to decorate a test without changing its behavior")
]
public class TestDecoratorAddin : ITestDecorator, IAddin
{
    public bool Install(IExtensionHost host)
    {
        IExtensionPoint testDecorators = host.GetExtensionPoint( "TestDecorators" );
        if (testDecorators == null)
            return false;

        testDecorators.Install(this);
        return true;
    }

    public Test Decorate(Test test, MemberInfo member)
    {
        if (test.Properties.Contains("DecorateMe"))
            return new DoNothingTestDecorator(test);
        return test;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestToBeDecorated
{
    private bool setupRan = false;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        setupRan = true;
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        setupRan = false;
    }


    [Test]
    [Property("DecorateMe",1)]
    public void TestDecorated() // Fails
    {
        Assert.That(setupRan);
    }

    [Test]
    [Property("Nothing",1)]
    public void TestUnDecorated()  // Passes 
    {
        Assert.That(setupRan);
    }
}
```

**Nunit Output**

```
>nunit-console ExampleTests.dll
NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.8009 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-3.5
.F.
Tests run: 2, Errors: 0, Failures: 1, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.0489326845238935 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0

Errors and Failures:
1) Test Failure : ExampleTests.TestToBeDecorated.TestDecorated
     Expected: True
  But was:  False
```

Comment: Is there more? You only posted the class that replaces the test itself, not the addin code that installs it.

Comment: edit: Added installation code and example test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestMethod.Run(...) depends on having the Test.Parent property set.   The property is (incorrectly?) non-virtual, so can't be delegated by the decorator.

As a work around, the Parent property on the concrete class can be set in the decorated Run method as follows:

```
public class DoNothingTestDecorator : Test
{
/*...*/
    public override TestResult Run(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter)
    {
        concrete.Parent=this.Parent;
        return concrete.Run(listener, filter);
    }
/*..*/
}
```